# maxFileSize and acceptFileTypes in blueimp file upload plugin do not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Blueimp jQuery file upload plugin for upload files.

I had no problem in uploading but the option `maxFileSize` and `acceptFileTypes` do not work.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p style="color: green;">' + file.name + '<i class="elusive-ok" style="padding-left:10px;"/> - Type: ' + file.type + ' - Size: ' + file.size + ' byte</p>')
                    .appendTo('#div_files');
            });
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.messages, function (index, error) {
                $('<p style="color: red;">Upload file error: ' + error + '<i class="elusive-remove" style="padding-left:10px;"/></p>')
                    .appendTo('#div_files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello there,

I'm trying to implement this code for file upload but getting the error that says

Upload file error: Uploaded bytes exceed file size

Can you please suggest what is the cause?

Comment: @JayMaharjan Are you sure that the maxFileSize is properly configured?

Comment: After doing the proper configuration in php.ini now i'm able to upload large files. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: For my case, the gif was being resized and converted to png, and then filter for gif failed obviously. And strangely enough, it started working itself as soon as I figured out what is going on, I doubled checked if I had done something with the library but nothing, all I had put was console logs, which I removed and still working. Posting so this may help someone.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Had the same problem, and the blueimp guy says "[maxFileSize and acceptFileTypes are only supported by the UI version](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/760)" and has provided a (broken) link to incorporate the _validate and _hasError methods.

So without knowing how to incorporate those methods without messing up the script I wrote this little function. It seems to work for me.

Just add this

```
add: function(e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
        if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
            uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
        }
        if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 5000000) {
            uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
        }
        if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
        } else {
            data.submit();
        }
},
```

at the start of the .fileupload options as shown in your code here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        add: function(e, data) {
                var uploadErrors = [];
                var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
                if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
                    uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
                }
                if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 5000000) {
                    uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
                }
                if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
                    alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
                } else {
                    data.submit();
                }
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        // acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        // maxFileSize: 5000000,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p style="color: green;">' + file.name + '<i class="elusive-ok" style="padding-left:10px;"/> - Type: ' + file.type + ' - Size: ' + file.size + ' byte</p>')
                .appendTo('#div_files');
            });
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.messages, function (index, error) {
                $('<p style="color: red;">Upload file error: ' + error + '<i class="elusive-remove" style="padding-left:10px;"/></p>')
                .appendTo('#div_files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        }
    });
});
```

You'll notice I added a filesize function in there as well because that will also only work in the UI version.

Updated to get past issue suggested by @lopsided: Added `data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length` and `data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length` in the queries to make sure they exist and are not empty first before testing for errors. If they don't exist, no error will be shown and it will only rely on your server side error testing.

Comment: This is really useful. However it should be noted that `data.originalFiles[0]['type']` is empty when uploading from a browser that does not support the File API. This was the case on my Android phone. What I did was to pass it if this value is not available and then fallback to server-side mime type validation. Otherwise you never get past the `acceptFileTypes.test` line

Comment: @lopsided that is odd, I get the value for data.originalFiles[0]['type'] and ['size'] on my Android phone and it passes both tests. I'm actually having trouble with my phone where everything seems to work without error but the file doesn't get uploaded. No issues anywhere else, just the Android.

Comment: I haven't spent much time looking into this but I saw in the `jquery.fileupload.js` file around line 1073, the `_getSingleFileInputFiles` has a bunch of fallbacks to get the file info object. There is a comment there that says `// If the files property is not available, the browser does not support the File API and we add a pseudo File object with the input value as name with path information removed` so it does imply that the test you propose (while useful and probably works for > 90% of use cases, is not 100% reliable as I found out.

Comment: I think the condition 'data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length ' is deprecated therefore it always returns false.

Comment: Use data.files[0]['size'] and data.files[0]['type']

Comment: encounter the data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length problem from your update on archives ( rar, 7z )

Comment: @PaulMrG can you please take a look at my question I tried this solution but doesnt work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386928/restrict-filetype-size-single-upload-doesnt-work-in-jquery-file-upload

Comment: it seems to work fine but in safari data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length is undefined and skips the size check data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length has a value, if i alert data.originalFiles[0]['size'] i get the size

Comment: Using without 'length' 
(data.originalFiles[0]['size'] && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 500000) ? 'true' : 'false' works fine, but i want to know whether I am missing any scenario

1. data.originalFiles[0]['size'] ? 'true' : 'false'
(1) returns false for values 0, null, undefined

Comment: data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length returns undefined, length don't work for number so i converted to string like this data.originalFiles[0]['size'].toString().length

Comment: I see the use of `data.originalFiles[0]`, does it mean that it checks only the first file selected? What if you have multiple files selected?

Comment: If you have multiple files, then use a loop to verify them, at the end you get the files in a list. I have added the sample code as an answer to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52180828/5220805

Answer (score 49):

You should include [jquery.fileupload-process.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js) and [jquery.fileupload-validate.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js) to make it work.

Comment: This seems to be the better answer. ;)

Comment: The order you load scripts is important to get the error message appear : 

tmpl.min.js > jquery.ui.widget.js > jquery.iframe-transport.js > jquery.fileupload.js > jquery.fileupload-ui.js > jquery.fileupload-process.js > jquery.fileupload-validate.js

Comment: Problem is the same, can you provide some working example please?

Comment: Changing the order the scripts were loaded fixed it for me

Comment: I am having this same issue. My JS files are in the exact order described, yet I am still able to upload files that are both not accepted according to the regex, but also massively over the file size limit. I am using the latest FileUpload version, 9.10.5 with jQuery 1.11.1

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, even with all the scripts included in the correct order.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested in an earlier answer, we need to include two additional files - `jquery.fileupload-process.js` and then `jquery.fileupload-validate.js` However as I need to perform some additional ajax calls while adding a file, I am subscribing to the `fileuploadadd` event to perform those calls. Regarding such a usage the author of this plugin [suggested the following](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/760#issuecomment-35675651)

> Please have a look here:
>   https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-callback-options
>
> > > Adding additional event listeners via bind (or on method with jQuery 1.7+) method is the preferred option to preserve callback settings by the jQuery File Upload UI version.
>
> Alternatively, you can also simply start the processing in your own callback, like this:
>   https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js#L50

Using the combination of the two suggested options, the following code works perfectly for me

```
$fileInput.fileupload({
    url: 'upload_url',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    disableValidation: false,
    maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024,
    messages: {
        maxFileSize: 'File exceeds maximum allowed size of 1MB',
    }
});

$fileInput.on('fileuploadadd', function(evt, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var validation = data.process(function () {
        return $this.fileupload('process', data);
    });

    validation.done(function() {
        makeAjaxCall('some_other_url', { fileName: data.files[0].name, fileSizeInBytes: data.files[0].size })
            .done(function(resp) {
                data.formData = data.formData || {};
                data.formData.someData = resp.SomeData;
                data.submit();
        });
    });
    validation.fail(function(data) {
        console.log('Upload error: ' + data.files[0].error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Amith, I tried this and got following error: `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'process'`

Comment: It almost always means that `.fileupload()` was not called at the proper time. Without seeing the code, its almost impossible to diagnose. I suggest opening a new question and posting the relevant code, maybe as a jsfiddle.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Are you trying to establish the logic for 'fileuploadadd' inside the $fileInput.fileupload declaration? I had a similar error when I tried to fold Amith's example inside something like this: `$('#fileupload').fileupload({ 
blah : blah,
blah : blah,
})
$fileInput.on('fileuploadadd', function(evt, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var validation = data.process(function () {
        return $this.fileupload('process', data);
    });
...
`
It was obvious when I thought about it, but I was trying to define logic inside something I hadn't finished declaring yet.

Comment: i am getting this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: makeAjaxCall

Answer (score 8):

This works for me in firefox

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    dataType: 'json',
    //acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(xml|pdf)$/i,
    //maxFileSize: 15000000,

    add: function (e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];

        var acceptFileTypes = /\/(pdf|xml)$/i;
        if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
            uploadErrors.push('File type not accepted');
        }

        console.log(data.originalFiles[0]['size']) ;
        if (data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 5000000) {
            uploadErrors.push('Filesize too big');
        }
        if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
        } else {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        }

    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        data.context.text('Success!.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please rewrite this answer so that it's in English? I know automated translators can sometimes make it hard to tell, but English is the only (non-programming) language we use here.

Comment: mind you, you don't have to be a cunning linguist to be able to figure out that nasatome is saying "This works for me: it's correct in firefox."

The upload error is "file size too large".

I'm Australian and I grew up speaking English, but I think there's a certain English speaking attitude.  "English is the only language we use here" is not true.  People here use many different languages.  It is however the policy of this site to have questions and answers in English.

Answer (score 3):

open the file named "jquery.fileupload-ui.js", you will see the code like this:

```
 $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {
        // By default, files added to the widget are uploaded as soon
        // as the user clicks on the start buttons. To enable automatic
        // uploads, set the following option to true:
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        autoUpload: false,
        // The ID of the upload template:
        uploadTemplateId: 'template-upload',
        // The ID of the download template:
        downloadTemplateId: 'template-download',
        。。。。
```

just add one line code --- the new attribute "acceptFileTypes",like this:

```
 options: {
        // By default, files added to the widget are uploaded as soon
        // as the user clicks on the start buttons. To enable automatic
        // uploads, set the following option to true:
        **acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,**
        autoUpload: false,
        // The ID of the upload template:
        uploadTemplateId: 'template-upload',
        // The ID of the download template:
        downloadTemplateId: 'template-d
```

now  you'll see everything is allright!~
you just take the attribute with a wrong place.

Comment: It's a bad idea to ever modify the core code of a plugin/library if you can help it.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got all the plugin JS's imported and in the correct order, but you're still having issues, it seems that specifying your own "add" handler nerfs the one from the *-validate.js plugin, which normally would fire off all the validation by calling data.process(). So to fix it just do something like this in your "add" event handler:

```
$('#whatever').fileupload({
...
add: function(e, data) {
   var $this = $(this);
   data.process(function() {
      return $this.fileupload('process', data);
   }).done(function(){
      //do success stuff
      data.submit(); <-- fire off the upload to the server
   }).fail(function() {
      alert(data.files[0].error);
   });
}
...
});
```

Comment: Solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Checked/Valid example for:

- multiple file inputs
- for one or **MULTIPLE FILES** upload - `$.grep()` to remove files from array with errors
- `image` and `audio` format
- dynamic file types from string by `new RegExp()`

Notice: `acceptFileTypes.test()` - check mime types, for adio file like `.mp3` it will be `audio/mpeg` - not only extenstion. For all blueimp options: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function(i){

    // .form_files is my div/section of form for input file and progressbar
    var $progressbar = $(this).parents('.form_files:first').find('.progress-bar:first');

    var $image_format = 'jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|gif';
    var $audio_format = 'mp3|mpeg';
    var $all_formats = $image_format + '|' + $audio_format;

    var $image_size = 2;
    var $audio_size = 10;
    var mb = 1048576;

    $(this).fileupload({
        // ...
        singleFileUploads: false,   // << send all together, not single
        // ...
        add: function (e, data) {

            // array with all indexes of files with errors
            var error_uploads_indexes = [];

            // when add file - each file
            $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {

                // array for all errors
                var uploadErrors = [];


                // validate all formats first
                if($all_formats){

                    // check all formats first - before size
                    var acceptFileTypes = "(\.|\/)(" + $all_formats + ")$";
                    acceptFileTypes = new RegExp(acceptFileTypes, "i");

                    // when wrong format
                    if(data.files[index]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.files[index]['type'])) {
                        uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');

                    }else{

                        // default size is image_size
                        var $my_size = $image_size;

                            // check audio format
                            var acceptFileTypes = "(\.|\/)(" + $audio_format + ")$";
                            acceptFileTypes = new RegExp(acceptFileTypes, "i");

                            // alert(data.files[index]['type']);
                            // alert(acceptFileTypes.test('audio/mpeg'));

                            // if is audio then size is audio_size
                            if(data.files[index]['type'].length && acceptFileTypes.test(data.files[index]['type'])) {
                                $my_size = $audio_size;
                            }

                        // check size
                        if(data.files[index]['size'] > $my_size * mb) {
                            uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
                        };
                    };

                }; // << all_formats

                // when errors
                if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
                    //  alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));

                    // mark index of error file
                    error_uploads_indexes.push(index);
                    // alert error
                    alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));

                };

            }); // << each


            // remove indexes (files) with error
            data.files = $.grep( data.files, function( n, i ) {
                return $.inArray(i, error_uploads_indexes) ==-1;
            });


            // if are files to upload
            if(data.files.length){
                // upload by ajax
                var jqXHR = data.submit().done(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //...
                     alert('done!') ;
                        // ...
                });
            } // 

        }, // << add
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $progressbar.css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
                );
        }
    }); // << file_upload

    //          
}); // << each input file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an example of event handler for Add event. Assumes that singleFileUploads option is enabled (which is the default).  Read more jQuery File Upload documentation how to bound with add/fileuploadadd event. Inside loop you can use both vars **this** or **file**. An example of getting size property: **this['size']** or **file.size**.

```
    /**
     * Handles Add event
     */
    base.eventAdd = function(e, data) {

        var errs = [];
        var acceptFileTypes = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
        var maxFileSize = 5000000;

        // Validate file
        $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
            if (file.type.length && !acceptFileTypes.test(file.type)) {
                errs.push('Selected file "' + file.name + '" is not alloawed. Invalid file type.');
            }
            if (this['size'] > maxFileSize) {
                errs.push('Selected file "' + file.name + '" is too big, ' + parseInt(file.size / 1024 / 1024) + 'M.. File should be smaller than ' + parseInt(maxFileSize / 1024 / 1024) + 'M.');
            }
        });

        // Output errors or submit data
        if (errs.length > 0) {
            alert('An error occured. ' + errs.join(" "));
        } else {
            data.submit();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in chrome, jquery.fileupload.js version is 5.42.3

```
     add: function(e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        var ext = data.originalFiles[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ['odt','docx']) == -1) {
            uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
        }
        if(data.originalFiles[0].size > (2*1024*1024)) {//2 MB
            uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
        }
        if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
        } else {
            data.submit();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. Works also on 9.21.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) { 
        var attachmentValue = 3 * 1000 * 1024;
        var totalNoOfFiles = data.originalFiles.length;
        for (i = 0; i < data.originalFiles.length; i++) {
            if (data.originalFiles[i]['size'] > attachmentValue) {
                $attachmentsList.find('.uploading').remove();
                $attachmentMessage.append("<li>" + 'Uploaded bytes exceeded the file size' + "</li>");
                $attachmentMessage.show().fadeOut(10000, function () {
                    $attachmentMessage.html('');
                });
                data.originalFiles.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        if (data.files[0]) {
            $attachmentsList
           .prepend('<li class="uploading" class="clearfix loading-content">' + data.files[0].name + '</li>');
        }
        data.submit();                    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone looking for commonly supported formats by server

```
3g2|3gp|3gp2|3gpp|aac|aaf|aca|accdb|accde|accdt|acx|adt|adts|afm|ai|aif|aifc|aiff|appcache|application|art|asd|asf|asi|asm|asr|asx|atom|au|avi|axs|bas|bcpio|bin|bmp|c|cab|calx|cat|cdf|chm|class|clp|cmx|cnf|cod|cpio|cpp|crd|crl|crt|csh|css|csv|cur|dcr|deploy|der|dib|dir|disco|dll|dllconfig|dlm|doc|docm|docx|dot|dotm|dotx|dsp|dtd|dvi|dvr-ms|dwf|dwp|dxr|eml|emz|eot|eps|esd|etx|evy|exe|execonfig|fdf|fif|fla|flr|flv|gif|gtar|gz|h|hdf|hdml|hhc|hhk|hhp|hlp|hqx|hta|htc|htm|html|htt|hxt|ico|ics|ief|iii|inf|ins|isp|IVF|jar|java|jck|jcz|jfif|jpb|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|json|jsonld|jsx|latex|less|lit|lpk|lsf|lsx|lzh|m13|m14|m1v|m2ts|m3u|m4a|m4v|man|manifest|map|mdb|mdp|me|mht|mhtml|mid|midi|mix|mmf|mno|mny|mov|movie|mp2|mp3|mp4|mp4v|mpa|mpe|mpeg|mpg|mpp|mpv2|ms|msi|mso|mvb|mvc|nc|nsc|nws|ocx|oda|odc|ods|oga|ogg|ogv|one|onea|onepkg|onetmp|onetoc|onetoc2|osdx|otf|p10|p12|p7b|p7c|p7m|p7r|p7s|pbm|pcx|pcz|pdf|pfb|pfm|pfx|pgm|pko|pma|pmc|pml|pmr|pmw|png|pnm|pnz|pot|potm|potx|ppam|ppm|pps|ppsm|ppsx|ppt|pptm|pptx|prf|prm|prx|ps|psd|psm|psp|pub|qt|qtl|qxd|ra|ram|rar|ras|rf|rgb|rm|rmi|roff|rpm|rtf|rtx|scd|sct|sea|setpay|setreg|sgml|sh|shar|sit|sldm|sldx|smd|smi|smx|smz|snd|snp|spc|spl|spx|src|ssm|sst|stl|sv4cpio|sv4crc|svg|svgz|swf|t|tar|tcl|tex|texi|texinfo|tgz|thmx|thn|tif|tiff|toc|tr|trm|ts|tsv|ttf|tts|txt|u32|uls|ustar|vbs|vcf|vcs|vdx|vml|vsd|vss|vst|vsto|vsw|vsx|vtx|wav|wax|wbmp|wcm|wdb|webm|wks|wm|wma|wmd|wmf|wml|wmlc|wmls|wmlsc|wmp|wmv|wmx|wmz|woff|woff2|wps|wri|wrl|wrz|wsdl|wtv|wvx|x|xaf|xaml|xap|xbap|xbm|xdr|xht|xhtml|xla|xlam|xlc|xlm|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx|xlt|xltm|xltx|xlw|xml|xof|xpm|xps|xsd|xsf|xsl|xslt|xsn|xtp|xwd|z|zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an extra function like:

```
    function checkFileType(filename, typeRegEx) {
        if (filename.length < 4 || typeRegEx.length < 1) return false;
        var filenameParts = filename.split('.');
        if (filenameParts.length < 2) return false;
        var fileExtension = filenameParts[filenameParts.length - 1];
        return typeRegEx.test('.' + fileExtension);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include **jquery.fileupload-process.js** and **jquery.fileupload-validate.js** to make it work.

Then...

```
$(this).fileupload({
    // ...
    processfail: function (e, data) {
        data.files.forEach(function(file){
            if (file.error) {
                self.$errorMessage.html(file.error);
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
//...
}
```

**processfail** callback is launched after a validation fail.

Answer (score 0):

- You can also use the file extension to check for the filetype.
- More simpler way would be to do something as given below inside add :

  ```
  add : function (e,data){
     var extension = data.originalFiles[0].name.substr( 
     (data.originalFiles[0].name.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
              switch(extension){
                  case 'csv':
                  case 'xls':
                  case 'xlsx':
                      data.url = <Your URL>; 
                      data.submit();
                  break;
                  default:
                      alert("File type not accepted");
                  break;
              }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple file, you use a loop to verify each of the file format, something like this

```
add: function(e, data) {
        data.url = 'xx/';
        var uploadErrors = [];
         var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
        console.log(data.originalFiles);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.originalFiles.length; i++) {
            if(data.originalFiles[i]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[i]['type'])) {
                    uploadErrors.push('Not an accepted file type');
                    data.originalFiles
                }
                if(data.originalFiles[i]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[i]['size'] > 5000000) {
                    uploadErrors.push('Filesize is too big');
                }
                if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {

                      alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
                }
        }
        data.submit();
      },
```