# jQuery File Upload - validate filesize and extension

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using jQuery File Upload, my code is:

```
$(function(){

        var ul = $('#upload ul');
     // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
        $('#upload').fileupload({
            maxFileSize: 500,
            acceptFileTypes:  /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            formData: {
                action: 'ja_upload_doc',
                cv_id: $('#cv_id').val(),
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
            },
            // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
            dropZone: $('#drop'),

            // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
            // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
            add: function (e, data) {

                // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
                var jqXHR = data.submit().success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log('Done');
               });
            },

            progress: function(e, data){
            },
            done:function(e, data){

                console.log(data);
            },
            fail:function(e, data){
                // Something has gone wrong!
                data.context.addClass('error');
            }

        });

    });
```

I'm including

- jquery.ui.widget.js
- jquery.iframe-transport.js
- jquery.fileupload.js
- jquery.fileupload-ui.js
- jquery.fileupload.css

Is there anything else I need to include to make the Validation work? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Had the same problem, this link has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451629/maxfilesize-and-acceptfiletypes-in-blueimp-file-upload-plugin-do-not-work-why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include jquery.fileupload-process.js and jquery.fileupload-validate.js files in this order to be able to validate.

Answer (score 7):

To validate filesize just use: `maxFileSize`

```
maxFileSize: 500 // in byte 1024 * 1024 = 1Mb // for maximum size
minFileSize: 1   // in byte also
```

and to validate extension use : `acceptFileTypes`

```
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

for more information read about this [option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)

Answer (score -4):

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function AddFileUpload() {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
         '" type="file" />' +'<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""  />' +
          '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
          'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
            document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
            counter++;
        }
    function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
            document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    }
    </script>

 html codes ////////////
 <div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red"> </asp:Label><br />
  <span style="font-family:Arial"><span style="color: #003366">&nbsp;Click to add files</span></span>
 <input id="Button1" onclick="AddFileUpload()" 
 style="height: 27px; width: 74px;" tabindex="25" type="button" value="add" /><br /> <br /><br />
  <div id="FileUploadContainer">
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""  />
  <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->
                                                                                          </div>                                                                                         <br />                                                                                         <br />                                                                                          <br />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
<br /><br />
/<TD>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are clearly off topic since the OP question is about jQuery and you are posting about plain javascript. Plus, please add some more details on your answers than just code blocks.

Comment: Not to mention the OP's question has nothing to do with ASP.NET.