# Jquery file upload autoupload and frontend validation before upload

Tags: angularjs, file, validation, upload, blueimp

I use plugin from: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

My script loading order is:

jquery.js, angular.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.iframe-transport.js, jquery.fileupload.js, jquery.fileupload-process.js, jquery.fileupload-validate.js, jquery.fileupload-angular.js

My controller is:

```
$scope.profileUploadOptions = {
        url: API_URL + "images/user",
        maxFileSize: 50,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        forceIframeTransport: false,
        add: function(e, data) {

            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                console.log("Added file: " + file.name);
            });

            console.log(data);

        },
        start: function(e) {

            console.log("Uploads started");

        },
        stop: function (e) {

            console.log("Uploads finished");

        },
        change: function (e, data) {

            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                console.log("Changed file: " + file.name);
            });

        },
        progress: function(e, data) {

            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            console.log("Progress: " + progress);

        },
        progressAll: function (e, data) {

            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            console.log("Progress: " + progress);

        },
        done: function(e, data) {

            console.log("Done: ");
            console.log(data);

        },
        fail: function(e, data) {

            console.log("Fail: ");
            console.log(data);

        },
        always: function(e, data) {

            console.log("Always: ");
            console.log(data);

        }

    };
```

How i can submit upload after browse single file from browse window, and where i can handle errors if file type not in acceptFileTypes Regex, or is bigger than maxFileSize?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#autoupload) should answer your question on auto-uploading, and there are a [host of examples](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) that are easy enough to find regarding setting up the fileinput piece of your question.

As far as validating files before submitting an upload, [this posed answer, pasted below, is a good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446325/719539).

```
$fileInput.fileupload({
  url: 'upload_url',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  autoUpload: false,
  disableValidation: false,
  maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024,
  messages: {
    maxFileSize: 'File exceeds maximum allowed size of 1MB',
  }  
});

$fileInput.on('fileuploadadd', function(evt, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var validation = data.process(function () {
        return $this.fileupload('process', data);
    });

    validation.done(function() {
        makeAjaxCall('some_other_url', { fileName: data.files[0].name, fileSizeInBytes: data.files[0].size })
        .done(function(resp) {
            data.formData = data.formData || {};
            data.formData.someData = resp.SomeData;
            data.submit();
        });
    });
    validation.fail(function(data) {
        console.log('Upload error: ' + data.files[0].error);
    });
});
```

Using the other author's code, the providing user feedback can be achieved in the `validation.fail` handler.