# ( JQuery File Upload ) maxFileSize behaving weirdly

Tags: jquery

My option is behaving in a weird fashion, I can't figure out if it is using a unit I don't know, or if it is simple bugging.

For instance, setting it to 12000 allows me to upload files about ~50ko but not ~120ko, while setting it to 15000 allows me to upload 850ko files.

It also seems to depends on the type of files (sometimes a 850ko png will be uploaded whereas a 850ko jpg won't).

Would anyone have a clue what the issue might be ?

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 12000,
    progressInterval: 10,
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMinWidth: 150,
    imageMaxWidth: 150,
    imageMinHeight: 150,
    imageMaxHeight: 150,
    imageCrop: true,
    processfail: rest of the code...


<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
        <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
        <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
        <!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
        <!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
        <!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
        <script src="/core/scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be happen over not supporting browser File API. U can be use tricky method as in this issue,

[maxFileSize and acceptFileTypes in blueimp file upload plugin do not work. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451629/maxfilesize-and-acceptfiletypes-in-blueimp-file-upload-plugin-do-not-work-why)

Above answer wrote with deprecated function data.originalFiles[0]. instead of that use data.files[data.index]